# How can I change the offset of a timestamp and then store the change in postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

I have a form on my rails app that allows you to create a campaign object where the user can set a `start_date`, `end_date`, and `timezone` for which the dates will officially start and end.

What I would like to do is to apply the offset of the selected timezone to both the `start_date` and `end_date`. I've tried a few combinations but I can't seem to make it work. For starters, when I select my start and end dates for 11:00 PM and select Central Time Zone CDT with offset of `-0500`, the end result in postgresql is the following timestamp.

```
# No offset is applied
Wed, 08 Jun 2022 23:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00
```

In order to try to apply the offset, I've tried a few combinations in my rails code. Here are some examples in a `before_validation` callback. It's pseudocode but this is the gist of it.

Example #1

```
 date_tmp = send("start_at") # Wed, 08 Jun 2022 23:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00

 date_string = date_tmp.to_datetime.change(offset: '-0500').to_s

 assign_attributes("start_at" => date_string) # "2022-06-08T22:00:00-05:00"
```

The result is no change for example 1.

Example #2

```
 date_tmp = send("start_at") # Wed, 08 Jun 2022 23:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00

 date_string = date_tmp.to_datetime.change(offset: '-0500').to_s

 dt = Chronic.parse(date_string.to_time.to_s)

 assign_attributes("start_at" => dt) # "2022-06-08 22:00:00 -0500"
```

None of these variations work. I've also tried to save to postgresql timestamps that look like this:

```
2022-06-08T22:00:00-05:00
2022-06-08 22:00:00 -0500
Wed, 08 Jun 2022 22:00:00 -0500
```

I don't understand why rails and postgresql can't save the timestamp with the adjusted utc_offset that I want. What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try `new_offset` method on your `DateTime` instance.
It duplicates `datetime object` and resets its offset.

Some examples:

```rb
date = DateTime.now 
date # => Thu, 16 Jun 2022 20:14:58 +0000
date.new_offset('+03:00') # => Thu, 16 Jun 2022 23:14:58 +0300
date.new_offset('-03:00') # => Thu, 16 Jun 2022 17:14:58 -0300
```